# Angular 8 save array in cookie

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, angular6, ngx-cookie-service

I am using [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) package

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "id": 109,
            "name": "name1",
            "job" : "job name"

        }
    ],
    "token":"xxxx"
}

    this.cookieService.set( 'user_id', result.user.id );
    this.cookieService.set( 'user_name', result.user.name );
    this.cookieService.set( 'user_job', result.user.job );
```

How can I save this as a JSON array instead of saving individual?

like `this.cookieService.set( 'user', result.user );`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and save it and then [`parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get the value back

To set the value:

```
this.cookieService.set('user', JSON.stringify(result));
```

To retrieve the value:

```
JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get('user'));
```

Comment: Is there an upper limit for  number of characters?

Answer (score 2):

Here is example for adding Object in Cookie

```
this.cookieService.set( 'user', JSON.stringify(result));
```